# Confused about java set and get methods

Tags: java, methods, setter, getter

I'm really not able to figure out, how can I use set and get methods in different classes. I simply just need to have 2 classes - class one, class two. In class one I have set and get, which work properly, but I want to have get method in class two, that will return me same text as get method in class one.

Class one works fine, but what should I put to class two?

```
public class one {

private String name;

public one() {
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

}
```

Comment: How are class one and two related? two _has a_ one or two _is a_ one? Or simply the share the same String?

Comment: When you say you want two classes, do you really mean you want 2 instances of the same class?  Why do you want a method in what you call "class 2" to return the same text as as a method in class 1?

Comment: "return me same text as get method in class one." He wants to access private data of class 1 from class 2, basically.

Comment: This question need editing. What about class 3? or class 4? or so on... You must make your question so specific that the users here can give certain answers to your specific programming problem instead of assuming, guessing (or parsing) what you try to ask.

Answer (score 3):

I think you  may be trying to do too much all at once as a newcomer.

Understand, first, that a Class is just a template or a blueprint for an object. Beyond that, "Get"ters and "Set"ters are really just public "wrappers" around private data in your class. This lets you, as the class author, control the data coming into your class and leaving it. That's really all there is to it.

With that in mind, Getters and Setters don't have any idea or notion about any other class or instances (unless they just happen to be a member of that class, which I don't think is the case here). So the idea of having one "getter" in one class return a value from another class doesn't quite add up.

Comment: Unless the instance of class one delegates to an instance of class two to implement the getters and setters.

Comment: True, as it also could be with various subclassing scenarios, but I just don't think the OP is conveying a problem anywhere near that complex.

Comment: Agreed. I don't think he actually knows yet what classes and objects are.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the methods from `one`, make class `two` as subclass of `one` as :

```
 public class two extends one {
 }
```

Better to use right naming convention (make initial letter in class name as capital):

```
public class One {
}

public class Two extends One {
}
```

Hope this works to you.

Answer (score 0):

The setter and getter methods will be individual for both the classes.

```
Class1 { 
    int a; float b;

    void setA(int a) { this.a = a; }

    int getA() { return this.a; }
}

Class2 { 
    String s;

    void setS(string str) { this.s = str; }

    String getS() { return this.s; }
}
```

Apart from this there is nothing that much complex with setter and getter methods.

if there is any particular requirement for you in which you always want to return the value which `Class1` getter gives,

then in `Class2` getter() method, do

```
String getS()
{
    return obj1.getA().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setters and Getters are methods used to obtain the value of the field of a class. They're a codig practice that makes you independent of the logic behind that value, because you can return a simple value

```
public String getName() {
    return value; 
}
```

or do something more sophisticated:

```
public String getName() {
    String modValue = new String();
    //Lots of code here
    return modValue;
}
```

Should you need to return something else or do something different, the classes interacting with this particular class will still call a setter and a getter without being affected (unless you make a major change like changing the type of the value...).

```
One classOne = new One();
one.getValue(); //returns the value or executes some logic before. It doesn't matter
                //if it changes because the method is the same. Your classes do not
                //depend on each other.
```

The alternative to a getter is... this...

```
classOne.value;
```

You access the field directly which is a code smell, a disaster and many adjetives I don't have a thesaurus for. This way if you need to do something to value before returning it (Think of this as if you return a number and you now need to round it... you have to change all your code or round it every time you get it. With a getter you can round it before returning it).

You should consider your design here, because if you want to return a value that's exaclty the same of the value from other class you can consider having an instance of class `one` into class `two` and delegating the getter call only if they're related in a way that justifies that. If the objects are not related, you should set that value yourself.

The setters and getters are defined for each class because they're related to each particular context. You cannot define a getter that's invoked or related to another class, unless those classes are related either because one contains the other or because there's some connection between them such as (to give some examples):

1. An external agent duplicating values
2. An external object shared by both classes
3. A common source of data for both classes to handle
4. One class is the extension of the other and the second class is
   overriding the methods.